# Как убрать знак вопроса из строки в консоли?

Tags: c#

Вот код:

```
float price = 2.7530f;

Console.WriteLine($"${price * 100:C}k");
```

Он должен вывести так: `$275.30k`. Но он мне выводит знак вопроса между последней цифрой и k.
Как его убрать?

Скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Матчасть](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.single.tostring?view=netcore-3.1) - не стесняйтесь читать документацию.

Answer (score 2):

"C" - это [описатель формата валюты](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-currency-c-format-specifier). При его использовании к выводимому значению автоматически добавляется символ валюты той культуры, которая установлена в данный момент.

Очевидно, у вас код запускается на русскоязычной Винде, в которой стоит русский язык по умолчанию. При этом должен выводиться знак "₽" - символ рубля. Но проблема с кодировкой.

Шло третье десятилетие двадцать первого века, проблемы с кодировками в консоли продолжали существовать...

Если, например, вы добавите в код строку `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;` то получите вывод `275,30 ₽k`.

Но вы добавляете к значению символ доллара: `$`. Из этого можно сделать вывод, что вам нужен вывод денежных значений в культуре `en-US`.

Можете задать её как глобально:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Console.WriteLine($"{price:C}k");
```

так и локально:

```
Console.WriteLine(price.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-US")) + "k");
```

В обоих случаях получите результат `$275.30k`.

Обратите внимание, при этом не нужно вручную добавлять символ доллара `$`.

Также обратите внимание, что в русскоязычной культуре в качестве десятичного разделителя будет запятая, а в англоязычной - точка.

Answer (score 0):

Для исчисления денежной стоимости используйте тип данных `decimal`
Перепишите код и запустите отладку :)

Comment: Замечание про то, что для денежных величин следует использовать `decimal` верное. Но это не объясняет, откуда появляется знак вопроса.

Comment: Я считаю, что это не ответ, он не объясняет, что это за знак вопроса, и как это починить.

Comment: И это скорее про точное хранение денежных данных, а не про их репрезентацию, ага.

Comment: Вопрос был как убрать, я ответил как.

Comment: Нет, вы не ответили. Замена `float` на `decimal` не решит проблему.